# How do I keep track when someone clicks on a link?

Tags: php

I want to be able to keep a txt file on my server of all the pages where a particular link is clicked. I have a link that people click to report content. I want to be able to know which URL the person was on when that link was clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: If those links all lead to your site, then you can track page referrer header. Also, I'm pretty sure google analytics can do that out of the box.

Comment: I would definitely use google analytics for this!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
file_put_contents(
    './urllog.txt',
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . PHP_EOL,
    FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX
);
```

Though I will say, there are much better ways to do what you want. If you only want it temporarily, a keystore like Redis is a good fit. If you're on a simple LAMP, a table to log this in would be much better. Generally you shouldn't use text files as your datastores nowadays.

Best solution (and what everyone uses) is to abandon the idea of storing it yourself, and simply use Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
error_log($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 3, "Path of Log File");
```

3 means message is appended to file...

Comment: What is this `3` for? What does `error_log` do? Please edit your answer to explain your code.